# Allow WRITE access to local folders machine in 2003SBS AD

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, domain, user-profile

Have a SBS2003 client with a mess of a domain that is in process of being cleaned.

But, for the life of me I cannot find a setting that will allow write access to the local hard disk for domain users with redirected profiles(to the server).  This is needed only for one program that will not follow a symbolic link to the network path, instead it seems to be hard coded to the %appdata% folder but only on the c: drive....

So question is how can I allow "Domain users" write access to the local %appdata% directory? I have tried setting it manually on a machine but it kept resetting to RO no matter how many times I tried. Every time I would un-check the RO property it would reset sometime right after i hit OK.

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that users needed to have priv's to local computer.

Using control userpasswords2 as an admin I added the domain\user and all was righted.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely inheriting permissions from a parent folder. You will need to prevent it from inheriting permissions and then try again. This however is quite a bodged fixed and whoever coded that software should be ashamed!

Comment: I don't think it is an inheritance issue, but more of a GPO issue and I can't seem to find that corresponding GPO entry as I didn't setup the original server. And Yes, I told them many times that there software is a POS